# Does there exists an entire function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ which is bounded on real line and imaginary line?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exists a nonconstant entire function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$  which is bounded on real line and imaginary line?

Clearly,$ f(z)=sin(z)$ is an example of an entire function which is bounded on real line and $ f(z)= e^z$ is example of a function which is bounded on imaginary line.But I'm unable to find a function which is bounded on both the lines.Any ideas?

Comment: See this Math Overflow page for some really good answers towards this direction: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/190837/entire-function-bounded-at-every-line

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think thats more general.There may be some easy example in OP's case.

Comment: @Learner For sure.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

$f(z) =e^{iz^2}$ will do that for you.

Comment: You should remove some of the ellipses.

Comment: @CameronWilliams  I have them to meet the character lower limit.

Comment: Use \, in $\rm\LaTeX$ to put in artificial spaces.

Comment: @zhw. Sorry..How did you thought of such example?

Comment: @Learner: I imagine that zhw considered first what functions send exactly the real and imaginary lines to the real line. One such function is $z\mapsto z^2.$ Hence $z\mapsto iz^2$ maps exactly the real and imaginary lines to the imaginary line, whence composition with $w\mapsto e^w$ yields the desired result. A similar approach is to consider $\sin(z^2)$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you.Regards,

Comment: @Learner What CameronBuie said is pretty much right.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you for your response.Regards,

Comment: Nice Example.....

Answer (score 0):

Another is $e^{ie^z}$. On real line it is $|e^{ie^x}|=1$ and on imaginary axix it is $|e^{i \cos y -\sin y}|\leq e$.